# How to Return Multiple Columns from Pandas using the Apply Function

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Long time reader first time poster.
Self teaching myself Python and usually manage to brute force my way through a problem or find the answer on here but I have been stuck on this for days now.

I have a function:

```
def Main(row):

LessThanPiv = HighPiv.iloc[np.where((HighPiv.High.values > row.Close) & (HighPiv.index.values < row.name))]

    Less_Than_Piv = pd.DataFrame()

    counter = 1
    a = 1
    while counter ==1:
        if LessThanPiv.empty:
            break
        FirstBroken = LessThanPiv.head(a)
        BrokenPivRows = df.iloc[np.where((df.index.values > FirstBroken.index.values) & (df.index.values <= row.name))]
        BrokenPivs = BrokenPivRows.iloc[np.where(BrokenPivRows.Close.values < FirstBroken.High.values)]
        Less_Than_Piv = LessThanPiv.append(BrokenPivs)
        a += 1
        if len(FirstBroken) == 1:
            break
    if Less_Than_Piv.empty:
        ClosestPiv = HighPiv.iloc[(HighPiv.index.values < row.name).astype(float)]
        ClosestPiv = ClosestPiv.tail(1)
        ClosestPiv_Volume = ClosestPiv.Volume.values
        ClosestPiv_Close = ClosestPiv.Close.values
        ClosestPiv_Open = ClosestPiv.Open.values
        ClosestPiv_Date = ClosestPiv.Date.values
        ClosestPiv = ClosestPiv.High.values
    else:
        ClosestPiv = df.iloc[(Less_Than_Piv.High.sub(row.Close).abs().idxmin())]
        ClosestPiv_Volume = ClosestPiv.Volume
        ClosestPiv_Close = ClosestPiv.Close
        ClosestPiv_Open = ClosestPiv.Open
        ClosestPiv_Date = ClosestPiv.Date
        ClosestPiv = ClosestPiv.High
    if row.Close < ClosestPiv:
        BreakOutDay = Next_Day(row, 1)
        TradeDay = Next_Day(BreakOutDay, 1)
        if BreakOutDay.Close > ClosestPiv:
            if row.Volume > (3 * Average_Volume) and row.Close > row.Open or ClosestPiv_Volume > (3 * Average_Volume) and ClosestPiv_Close > ClosestPiv_Open:
                if row.Volume > (3 * Average_Volume) and row.Close > row.Open:
                    data['Spike Day'] = row.Date
                    data['Average Volume'] = [Average_Volume]
                else:
                    data['Spike Day Closest Piv'] = [ClosestPiv_Date]
                    data['Average Volume'] = [Average_Volume]

            TradeBuy = TradeDay['Open']
            FollDays = df.iloc[np.where(df.index.values >= TradeDay.name)]
            FallBack = FollDays.iloc[np.where(FollDays.Low < FollDays.Low.shift())]
            PulledBack = FallBack.iloc[np.where(FallBack.Close < (FallBack.apply(PullBack, Foll=FollDays, axis=1)))]

            TradeSell = PulledBack.head(1)

            if PulledBack.empty:
                TradeSell = df.tail(1)

            data['Ticker'] = [i]
            data['Breakout Date'] = BreakOutDay['Date']
            Data = data['Breakout Date']
            Win = TradeSell.Open.values - TradeBuy
            data['Profit'] = [Win]
            Profit = data['Profit']
            data['Buy Price'] = [TradeBuy]
            data['Sell Date'] = [TradeSell.Date.values]

            return [Ticker], [Profit]
```

I am calling it with

```
row[['Ticker', 'Profit']] = row.apply(lambda x:Main(x), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

No matter what I try I can't seem to get the results of "data" into a new dataframe or existing one for that matter. I've tried:

```
return pd.Series([Ticker], [Profit])
```

But I keep getting the same error

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

I know this is something I am doing wrong but I just can't work out what.

Comment: Have you tried putting .values at the end of your row.apply? Without assigning it to row[['Ticker','Profit']], look at what the left hand side looks like. Like what dimensions it has.

Comment: I put .values at the end of row.apply like the below but I am getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'.

This is what I currently have.

```
return pd.Series([Ticker], [Profit])
```
```
row[['Ticker', 'Profit']] = row.apply(lambda x:Main(x), axis=1, result_type='expand').values
```
When I have pd.Series, it is a list but Ticker and Profit both have 1 dimension by themselves.

Comment: when you don't assign it, and just look at the output, are the dimensions what you expect them to be?

Comment: I think I am starting to get somewhere. I changed the apply line to:
row[['Ticker', 'Profit']] = row.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Main(x)), axis=1, result_type='expand')
Return line:
return Ticker, Profit.values
Values are in the correct columns of the dataframe but:
DeprecationWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  row[['Ticker', 'Profit']] = row.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(Main(x)), axis=1, result_type='expand')

Comment: Also when I row.to_csv the Profit column is filled with values like [array([3.66000366])] instead of just the value.

Comment: But did you look at the dimensions of the output? @MasterofNone

Comment: not sure how to check the dimensions of the output without assigning it? Sorry new to all of this.

Comment: just look at the result of row.apply(lambda x:Main(x), axis=1, result_type='expand'). If you are using jupyter notebook it should print it out with the dimensions.

Comment: Not using jupyter. I tried a print statement and ndim but but neither worked.

Comment: print(row.apply(lambda x:Main(x), axis=1, result_type='expand').shape) resulted in (376,)
 and print(row.apply(lambda x:Main(x), axis=1, result_type='expand').ndim) resulted in 1

Comment: So what you have is a single array with length 376 (is this the same length as your dataframe?) but you were assigning it to two columns which is going to give you an error.

Comment: My dataframe is (376,7). Shouldn't return Ticker, Profit.values return (376,2) so I can add two more columns?

Comment: experiment with adding one column at a time and see how it goes. Seems like the dimensions fit.

Comment: When you say one column at a time do you mean loop though the apply for each column I want to add? This sort of goes against what I am trying to achieve which is returning multiple columns from the apply statement. I have a fully functioning program using a for statement but it is too slow hence the apply.

Comment: All im saying is just check if it works for 1 column, if it does then it should work for 2 and you are doing something else wrong. If it doesn't then there is some problem with the size or type of the array.

Comment: Oh I get what you are saying now. So the Ticker one works fine by itself but the Profit one seems to work fine until I send it to csv and in each cell it fills something like the below instead of the value.

0    [2.660003662109375]
Name: Profit, dtype: object

When I try and return Ticker and Profit though it doesn't work.

Comment: So it must be an issue with the profit column.

Comment: I think I worked out the Profit column problem. I added Profit = np.concatenate(Profit).astype(None) before returning it. This didn't fix the problem though as now I get ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable. If I change back to row[['Ticker', 'Profit']] = row.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Main(x)), axis=1, result_type='expand') everything works as expected but I get a repeating warning saying DeprecationWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.

Comment: Just worked out the warning problem. Sometimes the function would return nothing so instead I made it return np.nan if there was nothing to return. Then I just dropped the NaN values from the dataframe. Thanks for helping me through this le_camerone!

Comment: All good. Good luck.